# Adding new line in the text-area query-string is not passing through the value to the next page ERROR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textarea, query-string

I want add multiple line breaks in the textbox. I want shift the content using query string in C# code.

```
Response.Redirect("adddefectdata.aspx?id=" + txtsource.Text + "&score=" + txtscore.Text + "&case=" + txtcassee.Text + "&hd0=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_diagnosis.Value)) + "&hd1=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_probing.Value)) + "&hd2=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_solution.Value)) + "&hd3=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_empathy.Value)) + "&hd4=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_response.Value)) + "&hd5=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_categorization.Value)) + "&hd6=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_value.Value)) + "&hd7=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_presentations.Value)) + "&hd8=" + (Convert.ToInt32(txt_language.Value)) + "&hd9=" + (Convert.ToDouble(txt_actions.Value)) +  "&detail1=" + txt_ddetail1.InnerText + "&detail2=" + txt_ddetail2.InnerText + "&detail3=" + txt_ddetail3.InnerText

+ "&detail4=" + txt_ddetail4.InnerText
+ "&detail5=" + txt_ddetail5.InnerText
+ "&detail6=" + txt_ddetail6.InnerText
+ "&detail7=" + txt_ddetail7.InnerText
+ "&detail8=" + txt_ddetail8.InnerText
+ "&detail9=" + txt_ddetail9.InnerText
+ "&detail10=" + txt_ddetail10.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a HUGE query parm list, and THEN on the other page have to somehow un-ravel all that mess again.

Build a simple class, and pass that to the next page in session.

Say, like this:

```
    class clsDefectData
    {
        public string ID;
        public string score;
        public string sCase;
        public double diagnosis;
                   
        public double probing;
        public double solution;
        public double empathy;
        public double response;
        public double categorization;
        public double value;
        public double presentations;

        public int language;
        public double actions;
        public List<string> details = new List<string>();

    }

    void ExampleCode()
    {
        clsDefectData cDefect = new clsDefectData();

        cDefect.ID = txtsource.Text;
        cDefect.score = txtscore.Text;
        cDefect.sCase = txtcassee.Text;
        cDefect.diagnosis = Convert.ToDouble(txt_diagnosis.Value);
        cDefect.solution = Convert.ToDouble(txt_solution.Value);
        cDefect.empathy = Convert.ToDouble(txt_empathy.Value);
        // etc etc etct
        string strControl = "";
        this.t
        for (int i = 1;i <- 10;i++)
        {
            strControl = "txt_ddetail" + i;
            HtmlGenericControl cntrl= (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl(strControl);
            cDefect.details.Add(cntrl.InnerText);
        }

        Session["Defects"] = cDefect;

        Response.Redirect("adddefectdata.aspx");
```

The above is air code, but you get the idea. Not only will this keep things like line feeds in those text box(s) intact, but you enjoy intel-sense, and better yet, you can pass that "whole" thing as one paramter in any function or code that you have.

So, on the target page, you can now go:

```
    public clsDefectData cDefect = new clsDefectData();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cDefect = (clsDefectData)Session["Defects"];
    }
```

So, now any and all code behind in that target page has full use of all those values, and you don't have that "difficult" mess of a long query parameter string in the URL.

And you also enjoy nice intel-sense. If you pass that whole thing as a query parameter, then all of the conversion for double etc. will have to occur again.

You could consider passing as a json string, but really, I just don't see the need.

Create a little helper class. It will also allow you in code to not figure out what the heck is hdr2, when in fact it supposed to be "solution" value.

So, even from a "bugs" point of view, you will struggle to pass all that information as a URL query parameter, and worse on the other side (the target page), you have to re-do all of the "type" conversions to double etc.

and a big bonus?
Your URL don't look like garbage, and even better is then users can't mess with the URL and change those values anyway.